# Why is my implementation of inits failing?

Tags: haskell

Here's how I've implemented it:

```
inits' :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits' [] = [[]]
inits' xs = inits'(init xs) : xs
```

I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[[a]]’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      inits' :: forall a. [a] -> [[a]]
  Expected type: [[[a]]]
    Actual type: [a]
• In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘xs’
  In the expression: inits' (init xs) : xs
  In an equation for ‘inits'’: inits' xs = inits' (init xs) : xs
```

seems that to produce inits I'd have to call init on every sublist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? The result of `:` and its right operand have the same type. The expected result type is `[[a]]` (as per your type signature), but `xs` has type `[a]` (also per your type signature).

Comment: how would you solve it? i am not in school, i am doing this for fun.

Comment: @melpomene, while what you say is true, the error message is actually complaining Amy something else: the mismatch between the types of the two arguments to `(:)`. Based on the type of the first argument, it's expecting the second argument to have type `[[[a]]]` but sees it has type `[a]`. In fact, both arguments have the wrong types to match the expected result type, but the type checker only reported the first problem it noticed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you've designed this as a mirrored version of

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails' [] = [[]]
tails' xs = xs : tails' (tail xs)
```

The reason that works is that the `:` operator prepends a single element `xs` to a list. This could also be written

```
tails' xs = [xs] ++ tails' (tail xs)
```

But in `inits'(init xs) : xs`, this doesn't apply: the single element would be `inits'(init xs)`, but that's in fact already a nested list. The `++` version would however work:

```
inits' xs = inits'(init xs) ++ [xs]
```

Mind, this is pretty inefficient, because `++` always needs to traverse the entire LHS list, and this happens over and over in the recursion.

Comment: Thanks. whats a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How about looking the standard implementation?

Comment: i tried finding this but couldnt. do you have a link?

Comment: Use [Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=inits), click [the `Data.List` version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits), then [on `Source`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#inits). — Admittedly, turns out the standard implementation is a bit complicated here, but that's apparently the way to go to make this inherently not so performance-great function run well.

Comment: @dopatraman, the simplest way to do it with very well-behaved and pretty good performance characteristics is `inits xs = [] : zipWith (\k _ -> take k xs) [1..] xs`. The standard library gets fancier to improve constant factors.